# How to classify Android Devices based on DPI values?

Tags: android, screen-resolution, dpi, hdpi, ppi

In Android, various devices are classified into different categories based on their density.

```
LDPI = 120 DPI
MDPI = 160 DPI
HDPI = 240 DPI
XHDPI = 320 DPI
XXHDPI = 480 DPI
XXXHDPI = 640DPI
```

Here my doubt is, if an Android device has density as "200 DPI", will it falls under which of the above category? (example: Nexus 5 have 217dpi,whether it'll come under HDPI or MDPI).

Can anyone say, what is the exact range for different densities(LDPI,MDPI,XXHDPI.....).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's not one density but rather ranges (often called "buckets"). This is [documented here](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) and this picture I post below should explain how to classify it correctly (it lacks `xxhdpi` and `xxxhdpi` though, but the rule is the same)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

TVDPI is around 200, and it uses the HDPI.  I posted a question a while ago about DPI [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20112596/drawable-xxxx-eclipse-versus-avd) and got no answers.

In [this table](http://checkscreensize.appspot.com/listdevice.jsp), devices in that range are classified as TVDPI, and the docs says that it is not necessary to have this folder and it uses images in the HDPI folder and downsizes them.

Comment: Thanks for the Link @Rick. It's very useful.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

> If you notice this image you will come to know

```
ldpi    100 - 140   
mdpi    141 - 199   
hdpi    200 - 319   
xhdpi   320 - 340
```

Comment: Is this values are tested one?

Comment: YES..up to X-HDPI but I would like to know about XX, XXX too :)

Comment: Can you please provide some link or citation?